# Automate the execution of a .ipynb file in AWS SageMaker by Websocket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-sagemaker

I have an issue. At November 10th before, my lambda code use websocket to communicate sagemaker which is okay to automatic execution of a .ipynb file. The code is below

```
import boto3
import time
from botocore.vendored import requests
import websocket

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sm_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
    notebook_instance_name = 'test'
    url = sm_client.create_presigned_notebook_instance_url(NotebookInstanceName=notebook_instance_name)['AuthorizedUrl']

    url_tokens = url.split('/')
    http_proto = url_tokens[0]
    http_hn = url_tokens[2].split('?')[0].split('#')[0]

    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url)
    cookies = "; ".join(key + "=" + value for key, value in s.cookies.items())

    ws = websocket.create_connection
      ("wss://{}/terminals/websocket/1".format(http_hn),  
      cookie=cookies, 
      host=http_hn, 
      origin=http_proto + "//" + http_hn,
      header=["User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"])


    ws.send("""[ "stdin", "jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/Scikit.ipynb --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3 --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=1500\\r" ]""")
    time.sleep(1)
    ws.close()
    return None
```

But when November 18th, I discovered that websocket connects getting the error. The error code is WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 200 OK. I can't figure out for a few days. Does anyone have a suggestion / solution?

I survey this article for many days. But I don't get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at automating your notebook using SageMaker Processing Jobs.
Kindly see this blog post here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/scheduling-jupyter-notebooks-on-sagemaker-ephemeral-instances/

Comment: My websocket send totally code is nohup jupyter notebook and activate conda env, finally execute ipynb. Shortly, my ipynb code needs to use sagemaker notebook conda env which is tensorflow2_py38. Can this blog execute ipynb by conda env tensorflow2_py38? If it can do, have any example?

Comment: In general you should not be looking to execute Jupyter notebooks on a SageMaker notebook instance. Instead you can look at using a Processing Job or Training Job. As described in the link above it uses a Processing Job which uses a docker container to run the Jupyter notebook. This link ( https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-schedule-jupyter-notebooks-in-amazon-sagemaker-d50fa1c8c0ad ) shows how to schedule a notebook instance with a specific kernel. However, this is not the recommended path.